# I'm trying to validate the callback send to my website in php

Tags: php

I'm trying to validate the callback send to my website in php.

Please I'm trying to use this api documentation https://support.cryptapi.io/article/how-to-verify-the-callback-signature to validate the callback send to my website but my code keep showing error to the api

I don't know whether it from my code

```
<?php


$pubkey = 
"-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nMIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQC3FT0Ym8b3myVxhQW7ESuuu6lo\ndGAsUJs4fq+Ey//jm27jQ7HHHDmP1YJO7XE7Jf/0DTEJgcw4EZhJFVwsk6d3+4fy\nBsn0tKeyGMiaE6cVkX0cy6Y85o8zgc/CwZKc0uw6d5siAo++xl2zl+RGMXCELQVE\nox7pp208zTvown577wIDAQAB\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";       


$signature = base64_decode($_SERVER['HTTP_X_CA_SIGNATURE']);
$algo = OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256;

// if request is GET
$data = "https://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";

// if request is POST
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');

if (openssl_verify($data, $signature, $pubkey, $algo) == 1) {



require "cryptapi.php";
$url = $_GET['userdata'];

$postdata = CryptAPI\CryptAPI::process_callback($_GET);
$amount = $postdata['value_coin'];
$txid_in = $postdata['txid_in'];

$data = array(
    'amount' => $amount,
    'txid_in' => $txid_in
);

$payload = json_encode($data);

// Prepare new cURL resource
$ch = curl_init(urldecode($url));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);

// Set HTTP Header for POST request 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($payload))
);

// Submit the POST request
$result = curl_exec($ch);

// Close cURL session handle
curl_close($ch);

echo "*ok*";


} else {
echo "error";
    // signature NOT valid
}
?>
```

Comment: It supposed to show *ok* to that api

Comment: What exactly is the error?

Comment: it supposed to show echo ok not error

Comment: So you're saying that `openssl_verify` returned false?

Comment: I don't know much about openssl_verify

Comment: OK. So have you tried to learn? Also you didn't actually answer my question. You don't need to know anything about the function just to tell me what it returns when you call it

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, ensure your callback URL can successfully execute action after payment if run manually e.g
https://example.com/verifypayment.php?order_id=908978675650&username=somebody&prod_id=200&amount=500&email=somebody@gmail.com&logticker=trc20_usdt
Add any getter `($_GET)` or setter `($_POST)` you may need as parameters but make sure there is a unique parameter which distinguishes the orders. In the above URL my unique parameter is `order_id`
My codes go like this in the `verifypayment.php`

```
    if(isset($_GET['order_id']) && isset($_GET['email']) && isset($_GET['amount']) && isset($_GET['logticker'])){
    $id = intVal($_GET['order_id']);
    $email = $_GET['email'];
    $logticker = $_GET['logticker'];//ENSURE YOU USE THE APPROPRIATE TICKER  https://cryptapi.io/cryptocurrencies/. SETTING TICKER AS PART OF YOUR  PARAMETERS MAKES THE USAGE OF DIFFERENT COIN TICKERS DYNAMIC AND FLEXIBLE
    $data = str_replace("@","%40",$data);//PLS ADD THIS LINE OF CODE IF EMAIL IS INCLUDED IN YOUR PARAMETERS TOO LIKE MINE CUZ CRYPTAPI SAVES @ IN ITS URLENCODE (%40)

    $query = array(
        "callback" => trim($data)
    );
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, [
        CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.cryptapi.io/" . $logticker . "/logs/?" . 
        http_build_query($query),
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
    ]);
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $error = curl_error($curl);
    curl_close($curl);        
    if ($error) {
        //echo "cURL Error #:" . $error; OR
        error_log("cURL Error #:" . $error,0);
    } else {
        //echo $response;
        $j = json_decode($response); 
        if(strcmp($j->status,"success")==0){//COMMAND EXECUTED SUCCESSFULLY IF APPROPRIATE URL IS CALLED
            $callbacks = $j->callbacks;//ARRAY OF DEPOSITS MADE INTO THE ADDRESS_IN
            if(is_array($callbacks)){
                $trans = count($callbacks);//NUMBER OF DEPOSITS MADE INTO THE ADDRESS_IN
                if($trans > 0){//IF ANY DEPOSIT IS MADE
                    $totalCoinDeposited = 0; $last_update = ''; $last_uuid = ''; $forwarded_amount = 0;
                    for($i = 0;$i < $trans;$i++){
                        $pending = intVal($callbacks[$i]->pending);
                        if($pending == 0){//IF DEPOSIT HAS BEEN CONFIRMED, IT S NO MORE PENDING
                            $value_coin = doubleVal($callbacks[$i]->value_coin);
                            $totalCoinDeposited += $value_coin;//GET THE SUM OF COIN SENT TO THE ADDRESS_IN
                            $last_update = $callbacks[$i]->last_update;
                            $last_uuid = $callbacks[$i]->uuid;
                            echo "TRANSACTION$i CONFIMRED<BR />";
                        }
                        if(strcmp($callbacks[$i]->result,"sent")==0){//IF DEPOSIT MADE HAS BEEN REMITTED INTO ADDRESS_OUT (YOUR OWN ADDRESS)
                            $forwarded_amount += doubleVal($callbacks[$i]->value_forwarded_coin);
                        }
                    
                    }
                    if($totalCoinDeposited >= doubleVal($_GET['amount'])){//IF TOTAL COIN SENT TO THE ADDRESS_IN IS UP TO THE AMOUNT EXPECTED
                        //YOUR CODES HERE WHEN THE TRANSACTION IS CONFIRMED SUCCESSFUL
                    }
                }
                else{
                    //echo "No deposit yet";
                    //error_log("No deposit yet",0);
                }
            }
                    
        }
        else{
            //echo "Callback URL not found";
            error_log("Callback URL not found",0);
        }

    }
            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ignore openssl_verify function first and use php curl function https://docs.cryptapi.io/#operation/logs
That's what I did to achieve my expectation

Answer (score 0):

CryptAPI\CryptAPI::process_callback($_GET) did not work for me, I used php curl provided at https://docs.cryptapi.io/#operation/logs

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: CryptAPI\CryptAPI::process_callback($_GET) did not work for me too. If you can follow the process I posted it works

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to add. In my own case my server MOD_SECURITY did not allow their webhook to run the callback url from their end so I use CRON to auto run it.
Ensure the callback url per order is stored in order table as well. There must be a column named order_confirmed or any name you can give it. Let your CRON loop the unconfirmed callback_urls via SQL query  E.g "SELECT callback_url FROM order_table WHERE order_confirmed = 0"

```
//Before your SQL while loop
$urls = array();
//In your query while loop
while(...){
    $urls[] = $callback_url; // WHERE $callback_url IS THE CALLBACK URL (VALUE) THAT COMES FROM THE COLUMN THAT STORES THE CALLBACK URL FOR AN ORDER
}

//After your query while loop

$curlMultiReq = curl_multi_init();
$ch = [];
foreach($urls as $key => $url){
    $ch[$key] = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch[$key], CURLOPT_HEADER, true);    // we want headers              
    curl_setopt($ch[$key], CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);    // we don't need body
    curl_setopt($ch[$key], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch[$key], CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,10);
    curl_multi_add_handle($curlMultiReq, $ch[$key]);
}
$running = '';
do {
    curl_multi_exec($curlMultiReq, $running);//THIS EXECUTES OR RUNS EACH CALLBACK URL AT THE BACKGROUND
    curl_multi_select($curlMultiReq);
} while ($running > 0);
foreach(array_keys($ch) as $key){
    //echo curl_getinfo($ch[$key], CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    //echo "\n";  
    curl_multi_remove_handle($curlMultiReq, $ch[$key]);
}
curl_multi_close($curlMultiReq);
```

ENSURE YOUR CALLBACK_URL UPDATE order_confirmed TO 1 IF THE TRANSACTION IS SUCCESSFUL SO THAT SUCCESSFUL TRANSACTIONS WONT BE LOOPED AGAIN

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a forum. Please don't post multiple different answers to the same question (unless they offer different, competing solutions to the problem). If all your answers are required in order to solve the problem then please consolidate them into a single answer. See also the [tour] and [answer] to understand more about how this site works - it's a Q&A format, not a linear discussion. Thanks.